# Matching against variable keys in `cl-case`

Tags: conditionals, cl

In [`cl-case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Conditionals.html#index-cl_002dcase) clauses (though naturally not the initial keyform), keys are apparently quoted:

```
(let ((mark ?.))
  (case mark
    (mark 'mark)
    (?. ?.))) ; 46 (?.)

(let ((mark ?.))
  (case 'mark
    (mark 'mark)
    (?. ?.))) ; mark
```

My reading of neither the cl-lib manual nor [CLHS entry for `case`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm) describe this behavior. Is this the intended behavior of `cl-case`? If so, is this behavior documented? Is there a succinct way to match the keyform against a variable in a `cl-case` (as opposed to using a `cond`)?

Comment: If you don't want to use `cond`, why not use [`pcase`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Pattern_002dMatching-Conditional.html)?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew: this question is about the semantics of an elisp construct. Wouldn't that be within the scope of that tag?

Comment: The more specific tag `conditionals` covers that. Just like the specific tag `elisp-macros` is appropriate for a question about Elisp macros.

Comment: @Drew: that's clearer, thanks.

Comment: (The problem with using tag `elisp` for anything that has to do with Elisp is that nearly everything in Emacs has to do with Elisp. The tag has little utility if it's used for everything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is actually described there, albeit in terse form:

- "Macro: cl-case keyform clause...": `cl-case` is a macro, macros do not evaluate their arguments.
- "This macro evaluates KEYFORM [...]": One of the arguments is evaluated, the rest aren't.
- Therefore the key forms aren't evaluated.

If you find yourself in that situation, just use `cond` and the appropriate equality predicate. To shorten matching for several keys, use `memq`, `memql`, `member` or `cl-find` with the `:test` keyword. In fact, I almost always use `cond` and only rarely resort to pattern matching constructs.